# Detect When new row is created in Quick edit view with the help of javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datasheet, quick-edit

I needed to apply certain validation on cells of **Quick edit**.

I can apply once it is loaded thereafter I need any event so that I can detect when the user has created a new row and call my validation function over that row.